# A float type granted to be bitwise equivalente on all / as much as possible platforms?

Tags: c++, c++11, floating-point

Is there a type in C++ that is able to handle floating point numbers and **is guaranteed** to be represented, at bit level, the same way in any possible implementation? Is there a similar solution for a limited set of architectures or even a single architecture like x86 or ARM?

I'm referring in particular to the scenario where I use atomic operations like [compare_exchange_strong](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/compare_exchange) on something like `std::atomic<float>` or `std::atomic<double>` .

Comment: Why would the bit representation need to be portable to use `std::atomic`?

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes because it's important when the comparison is at the bit level and involves the representation and not the represented value.

Comment: Why would that need a portable representation? Also, C++ already has tools to do bit-level comparisons. `float` is not one of them, so I fail to see why one would use `float` for that. `char` is the tool for that.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes compare_exchange_strong can fail if 2 floats have the same value but it is being represented in 2 different ways. I know that floats are bad for low level comparison, that's exactly what I'm trying to "fix".

Comment: If that's the case you are asking for the wrong thing. You don't need a portable representation. You only need a representation that has a 1-to-1 mapping of values to representations. If I'm not mistaken, any IEEE754-compliant system has that, and there is a macro you can use to check for IEEE754 compliance. Well, though that would still all go bonkers with NaNs.

Comment: If you want bit comparison, why not cast to int ?

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes as stated in my question, I only care about the representation, because that's the possible reason why a comparison of that kind can possibly fail, I will look into that 754 macro/check.

Comment: @Antoine ? how ? I don't want bit comparison, I want a comparison between 2 floats that is granted not-to-fail because of the representation, I don't need type punning .

Comment: What do you mean by "fail because of the representation"? Can you give an example of such failure? You may assume your implementation has two different representations for the number `0`, say `+0` and `-0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C++ standard does not make any guarantees, but [IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) does. If your implementation supports IEEE 754, then its floating point numbers are represented exactly the same way as in any other implementation that supports IEEE 754.

Comment: This is what you have asked for, but probably not what you really need.

Comment: what you mean with "not what you really need" ?

Comment: I mean that if you try apply this information to solve your problem, you will find out it's in fact useless. Your problem doesn't seem to involve portability of bit-representations between different implementations.

Comment: IEEE 754 does not guarantee byte ordering. Also, IEEE 754 binary formats have two representations for zero (+0 and -0), and IEEE 754 decimal formats have multiple representations for many values.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: IEEE 754 talks about e.g. 32-bit-long sequences of bits. These sequences may have different addressing schemes in different implementations. You have to account for that when working with the byte-oriented abstraction of physical memory (but you don't necessarily have to work at that level).

Comment: @EricPostpischil: the two representations of 0, and the many decimal representations, are all pairwise identical between IEEE-compliant platforms (which is what OP asked for) but not necessarily identical with each other (which is what he seems to need, or thinks to need).

Comment: I realize the OP likely does not need what they ask for. Nonetheless, this answer is incorrect. If two different processors (possibly even the same processor model, with different settings for endian configuration) access the same memory, the bits one writes for 3 might not appear to be 3 to the other due to endianness, and the bits one writes for -0 might not appear to be +0 to the other due to multiple representations of zero.

Comment: Once again. IEEE is not concerned with physical arrangement of bits in memory any more than it is concerned with voltage levels needed to represent 0 and 1. It talks about of 32-long sequences of binary values. How these sequences are mapped to bytes, voltages, or atoms is not of its concern. If you want compatibility at any of these levels, you need to make sure the mappings are compatible. You, not IEEE, because IEEE doesn't talk about these levels at all. It guarantees compatibility at the level of 32-long bit sequences. That's it.